# How can I hide mismatched appendix StyleRefs in the footer?

Tags: ms-word, reference, field, footer

I want to reference the appendix and the subsection of that appendix in my footer.
I'm currently using 4 StyleRef fields, referencing Appendix 1 and Appendix 2 data, but I encounter an issue with the start of a new appendix. The Appendix 2 retrievals will return the last test of the previous appendix.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iORBb.png)

I've had several ideas to prevent this:

1, Hide the field if it doesn't fetch the data from the current page,

2, Configure it to return nothing if the current page has the 'intentionally blank' statement,

3, Compare the last letter of Appendix 1 ID against first letter of Appendix 2 ID and return nothing if they don't match.

4, Setup these pages to use a different Header/Footer config to the other pages (please note, I already have 2 types of header/footer in this document, that are not linked. I do not know how to make a 3rd or selectively link pages to the different footers available in the document)

Does anyone know how I can set any of these up?

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. You may first want to look at http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/StyleRef.htm.